# Appbar popping out issue

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I am developing a windows phone 8.1 universal app and I have placed the application bar at bottom of the page. I have some buttons at bottom of the page and whenever I click buttons at bottom of the page,the app bar is popping out. It becomes a problem while playing with the bottom buttons while app bar is coming.I have made app bar as **ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"**,but same problem persist.

Is there any way to place app bar on top of the page or to hide the bottom appbar to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first way to do is just to hide *BottomAppBar* by setting its visibility:

```
BottomAppBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The other way may be to set it to *null*:

- create application bar in code,
- when you don't want bar to see at all just set `BottomAppBar = null;` in the code,
- as you have created the bar in the code, you have its reference, then when it's needed again just set it `BottomAppBar = myCommandBar;`.